# Concatenate i18next and Jade variable

Tags: javascript, pug, i18next

I want to output "You are logged in as [Username]" using i18next for the text and a Jade variable as the actual username, but I can't seem to get them working together.

As far as i can tell, i18n overwrites the WHOLE `<p>` to show "You are logged in as". The username is only shown, if I put it in a separate `<p>`, like so:

```
if (user)
  p(data-i18n='markup.loggedInAs')
  p #{user.username}
```

But then, of course, it gets rendered as a separate `<p>`, which is not what I want. I want both of them on a single line, ideally inside the same `<p>`. Is there a trick?

This:

```
if (user)
  p(data-i18n='markup.loggedInAs')
    | #{user.username}
```

doesn't work. The username is not shown at all :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with jade but I know i18next supports variable replacement with translations. Edit: not sure how to stop the markup but myVar is surrounded by two underscores. // given resources
{           
  'en-US': { translation: {  key: '__myVar__ are important' } }
};
 
i18n.t("key", { myVar: "variables" }); // -> variables are important

Comment: But that would cost me a lot of flexibility, if i want to use the variable in a couple of different places (like the username, in this case)
i would always have to pre-format the whole string, right?

Comment: Yes but with translations its hard to dynamically translate since orders of words and what not are very different across languages. You are logged in as [Username] can vary greatly across languages so having a translated string and only replacing the one variable means less flexibility better translatability.

Comment: well, that's a good point

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding here. I don't think you lose much flexibility here. You just want to translate "You are logged in as" across multiple languages and append a dynamic value right? But in some languages that value is not always just appended. It could start the sentence in another language. All this does in i18next is say there is a dynamic portion to this translation. It doesn't stop you from you using a variable else where but maybe you could explain how you think something is non reusable. I could be misunderstanding. =]

Comment: no, you're right. i think it's best done your way. but i'm facing the problem right now that this doesn't seem to work with the i18next-client (ajax) version? or at least i don't know how. i have the translation "loggedInAs": "Logged  in as __user__" (with underscores).in my json.
the var "user" exists in the jade template (it gets rendered as a p element), but the i18n output renders just the exact string i put into the json.
I think the problem is: the req.user comes from the server, while translations are loaded via ajax, and i need to find a way to stitch them together.. :/

Comment: Just a quick note... if you're trying to post code in comments, use backticks to surround it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the points in comments to your post are valid (word order is tricky in translation) I thought I'd point out how to solve the immediate problem.

```
p
  span(data-i18n='markup.loggedInAs')
  span #{user.username}
```

Note that this isn't tested, but I'm sure you can see how it (or something similar) would work. `span` is a better choice for marking up content that doesn't represent an actual paragraph.

Comment: thanks, this works for my problem :)
i'm gonna dig a little deeper for word ordering. right now, this suffices :)